# How to find particular class exists on a page using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to write JQuery which will find whether **Class="Mandatory"** exists on the page and if any element is having this class then only perform certain action.

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just check how many elements you hit, when you search for it with jQuery

```
if ($(".Mandatory").length > 0) {
    // Do stuff with $(".Mandatory")
    $(".Mandatory").each(function() {
        // "this" points to current item in looping through all elements with
        // class="Mandatory"
        $(this).doSomejQueryWithElement();
    }); 
}
```

**EDIT**
If you wanna do that check for your submit button click, just do that check after the click:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    if ($(".Mandatory").length > 0) {
        // Do some code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!, this mandatory class is being added dynamically on the submit button click, now I don't want to call until any of my element is having is class on it. Please suggest

Comment: You want to check only after you know the answer? I guess you could keep a flag that gets toggled on by the submit button click.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to only do the action once, you could use:

```
if ($('.Mandatory').length > 0) {
  //do your thing
}
```

Otherwise if you want to do it for each `Mandatory` element:

```
$('.Mandatory').each(function(){
  //do your thing
});
```

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do this is search class within the body tag.

```
$('body').find('.Mandatory').length;
```

Answer (score 6):

Basic jQuery (CSS) selector by class.

```
if($(".Mandatory").length)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go about it like so:

`$('*').hasClass('mandatory') ? "what to do if true" : "what to do if false"`

I find ternary conditions more useful as you can set variables more quickly

Answer (score 2):

using [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) you can find